# No space benefit using sparse Pandas dataframe despite extremely low density

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, sparse-matrix

I am using Python/Pandas to deal with very large and very sparse single-column data frames, but when I pickle them, there is virtually no benefit. If I try the same thing on Matlab, the difference is colossal, so I am trying to understand what is going on.

Using Pandas:

```
len(SecondBins)
>> 34300801

dense = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(SecondBins)),columns=['Binary'],index=SecondBins)
sparse = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(SecondBins)),columns=['Binary'],index=SecondBins).to_sparse(fill_value=0)

pickle.dump(dense,open('dense.p','wb'))
pickle.dump(sparse,open('sparse.p','wb'))
```

Looking at the sizes of the pickled files, 
dense = 548.8MB
sparse = 274.4MB

However, when I look at memory usage associated with these variables,

```
dense.memory_usage()
>>Binary    274406408
>>dtype: int64

sparse.memory_usage()
>>Binary    0
>>dtype: int64
```

So, for a completely empty sparse vector, there slightly more than 50% savings. Perhaps it was something to do with the fact that variable 'SecondBins' is composed of pd.Timestamp which I use in the Pandas as indices, so I tried a similar procedure using default indices.

```
dense_defaultindex = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(SecondBins)),columns=['Binary'])
sparse_defaultindex = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(SecondBins)),columns=['Binary']).to_sparse(fill_value=0)

pickle.dump(dense_defaultindex,open('dense_defaultindex.p','wb'))
pickle.dump(sparse_defaultindex,open('sparse_defaultindex.p','wb'))
```

But it yields the same sizes on disk.

What is pickle doing under the hood?
If I create a similar zero-filled vector in Matlab, and save it in a .mat file, it's ~180 bytes!?

Please advise.

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on here, but are you familiar with all the pandas storage options (including methods for pickle objects, that may be equivalent to what you're doing here)?  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html  In particular you might want to consider `to_hdf` which is a common way to store pandas dataframes and supports compression.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I've tried playing around with the .to_hdf function, but didn't get any visible improvements. For example, >>>SecondsDataFrame.to_hdf('sparse.hdf',key='thing',format='fixed',mode='w',complevel=9), yields ~274MB as well. I guess I'll just store the vectors in scipy.sparse format on disk and if I need to access one in Pandas for manipulation, I can generate the labels on the fly. Not ideal I guess, but I have thousands, so storing them in dense format is really not an option... if you have any better ideas, I'm all ears. Thanks :)

Comment: Right, b/c you're storing the index which is not sparse, as @TheBlackCat explains very well.  The advantage will be more if you have several columns, as the index only needs to be stored once, in which case you'd see a much bigger proportionate savings.  It all just depends on exactly what your data looks like and what you're doing with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that pandas is *labelled* data.  The column labels and the index labels are essentially specialized arrays, and those arrays take up space. So in practice the index acts as an additional column as far as space usage goes, and the column headings act as an additional row.

In the dense case, you essentially have two columns, the data and the index.  In the sparse case, you have essentially one column, the index (since the spare data column contains close to no data). So from this perspective, you would expect the sparse case to be about half the size of the dense case. And that is what you see in your file sizes.

In the MATLAB case, however, the data is not labeled.  Therefore, the sparse case takes up almost no space.  The equivalent to the MATLAB case would be a sparse matrix, not a spare dataframe structure.  So if you want to take full advantage of the space savings you should use `scipy.sparse`, which provides sparse matrix support similar to what you get in MATLAB.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comprehensive reply. I have tried the scipy.sparse library and it's as you say:

>>> from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
>>> sparse = csc_matrix((34300801,1), dtype=np.float)
>>> pickle.dump(sparse,open('sparse_cscmatrix.p','wb'))

The size of the pickled saved file is ~400bytes! I guess I will use that for all my vectors, and save the labels only once, separately. 
I understand that Pandas is labelled data; however, that's why I also tested it with the standard indices (which go from 0-len(array)), but I guess it's not clever enough...

Comment: Pandas doesn't try to be clever.  It always uses labels.  Even if you don't create them, they are still there.  If you don't want to use labels, just don't use pandas.  That being said, if you are create a lot of row matrices with the same indices, you can just use them as columns for a single dataframe rather than having a separate dataframe for each.  I think that would be simpler than keeping a separate index elsewhere.